# How to select rows in Teradata SQL based on complicated conditions in Teradata SQL?

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant, teradatasql

I have table in Teradata SQL like below:

```
col1        col2 
Jan Kowal  | Jan Kowal PHU
Bravo JohN | GB John BraVo
Ann Still  | Ronald G
```

And I need to select only these rows from above table where:

1. In col2 is value from col1 + something more (nevermind before or after)
2. Be aware that Jan Kowal and Kowal Jan is name and surname and it could be commutative
3. Case = False (nevermind whether letter are high or small)

So I need to select only first and second row:

```
col1          col2
Jan Kowal  | Jan Kowal PHU
Bravo JoHN  | GB John BraVo
```

- Because both rows have value from col1 + something more (before or after) in col2
- Case of letter = False
- name and surname and it could be commutative

Comment: Is the value in col1 always 2 words?

Answer (score 0):

You describe the first column as having a "name" and "surname" meaning that it has exactly two components.

For this problem, `strtok()` can help:

```
where regexp_instr(col2, strtok(col1, ' ', 1), 'i') and
      regexp_instr(col2, strtok(col1, ' ', 2), 'i')
```

I've used regular expressions here because it is simpler to modify it you want to consider word boundaries.  Your question is not clear on whether that is necessary.

Comment: Gordon first column not always have 2 words, could you modify your answer ?

Comment: @koler . . . I didn't make up the "2".  The question explicitly refers to the two components as "name" and "surname", implying very strongly that there are two.  If there is a known maximum, I would just continue using `regexp_similar()` to handle it.  However, for a general solution, you should ask another question.

Comment: Note that you probably want `regexp_instr` because `regexp_similar` requires a full-string match.